# Some elements in a list have delimiter and need to be separated. Then the other values for that element need to be copied to new row. Advice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is simplified... I have a matrix where *sometimes* the first column has cells that need to be delimited by ";". When that is the case, I want to copy the information for that row and create a new df with the appended row(s).

I have a key with values `key = [444, 555, 777]`

I also have a information_df where each item in the key exists, but sometimes within the same cell separated by ";". information_df looks like this.... and the output should look like this.... (both images in same url):

Example of input and ideal output:

[image]

Can anyone please advise on how to do this in python?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: The term you're looking for might be *unnest*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53218931/1424875.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the Numbers column values per row.

```
data = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    for num in str(row.Numbers).split(';'):
        row_data = [getattr(row, column_name) for column_name in df.columns 
                    if column_name != 'Numbers']
        data.append([int(num)] + row_data)
output_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: When I try to do that I also get the following error... Is this because it isn't recognizing all the values as strings?


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-f5d084a5fb5b> in <module>
      1 data = []
      2 for row in df.itertuples():
----> 3     for num in row.Numbers.split(';'):

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: yes apparently you have integers as well. I edited my answer with a solution for this

Comment: Thank you! This works great. So if I do this for a data set with more columns, all I have to do is add "row.xyz" in my data.append()?

Comment: yes, but if you don't like the typing a lot of column names you could do something like:
`data.append([int(num)] + [getattr(row, column_name) for column_name in df.columns])`

Comment: Can I do the same thing in the output_df line?

Comment: What thing exactly?

Comment: It gives me "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'" --> coming from the data.append line. Can you help me get around that?

Comment: It sounds like you have a missing value in your Numbers column

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly right. Any way I can add code that allows it to treat any blanks just like a string? Or ignore them altogether?

Comment: Tell me your solution and I will add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be best done using the `explode` function:

```
df['Numbers'] = df.Numbers.str.split(r'\s*;\s*')
df.explode('Numbers')
  Numbers Description          Date
0     444        Dark      9/2/2022
1     555       Light      9/3/2022
1     777       Light      9/3/2022
```

Comment: Whenever I do this on my df, it outputs NaN for any value that originally only had one number. For elements with multiple numbers separated by ";" it gives me something like [555, 777] on the same row still

Comment: @KyleReagan Probably your data is different from the one I had. Could you do `df.head().to_dict()` then post the data.

Comment: <bound method DataFrame.to_dict of     Numbers Description       Date
0       444        Dark 2022-09-02
1  555; 777       Light 2022-09-03>  <-- this is the practice one I'm using. it will output 444 as NaN

Comment: @KyleReagan you do have to share your data, IN TEXT FORMAT. not that you provide an image. Now I gave you a code that you should use to share your data. ie `your_data.to_dict()` then copy paste the results here. IF the data is large, you could use `your_data.head().to_dict()`